# How to get the variance explained by each term in a GAM

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I am applying a gam model and I would like to know how can I get the proportion of variance explained by each of them. The output using the summary is like that:
[image]

Do you know how can I get that?

I tried to use the complete model deviance and remove one variable at each time and see the difference. But it is not the proper way to do it...

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You ask about proportion of variance explained by "each of them:" to what does "them" refer?

Comment: Hi whuber. Each term (independent variable) AnnualIP and DegDays.

Comment: I saw in some places that the t^2 is equal to the F value. I believe that it is not true all the time, right? Because if it is, the DegDays explains more.

Comment: It is true for single terms only.  Because `s(DegDays)` requires multiple parameters, it needs an F test or the equivalent.  I am not sufficiently familiar with the underlying model to know what the correct numbers of degrees of freedom ought to be.  My approach would be to fit models with and without the variables you are interested in and compare mean squared prediction errors.  Remember, though--just as with unbalanced ANOVA--that you probably cannot attribute a definite proportion of explained variance to *any* variable, because they are likely correlated.